# how to check Composite Primary key before inserting new values

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table with multiple columns which consists of a composite primary key for three of them (columns customer_id,system_origin,policy_number).
The table is created as below :

```
Create table LOST_MEMBER_ACCESS_LOG (
Customer_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
System_Origin varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Policy_Number varchar2(20) NOT_NULL, 
PRIMARY_KEY(Customer_id,System_Origin, Policy_Number)
);
```

I have a requirement to write a stored proc which firsts checks if a row already exists for unique combination for customer_id,system_origin,policy_number then it updates the already existing row with the new values or else it inserts a new row.

Comment: MERGE is the command you're looking for. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: You can check the value existence using `LEFT JOIN` for both the cases `INSERT` and `UPDATE` but you need two write to separate queries `OR` you can check directly in the table then set the query conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying you want to do is:

```
if row exists then
   update ...
else
   insert ...
end if;
```

But there is easier way. Just do the update and check if any row was touched

```
update lost_member_access_log 
   set ...
 where ... ;
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
   insert into lost_member_access_log ...
end if;
```

[MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) is of course also an option.